# Grails - Retrieve Sign Up page or Home page without changing the URL

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails with Spring Security and would like that when the user enters my site root URL, it will receive a different page depends if he logged in or not.
1. Logged In - Home page with different data
2. Not logged in - Sign up page

I don't want to use Spring UI plugin and I don't want to use redirection because I want the URL to stay at the root url, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the root "/" of your application to a Controller you define (in UrlMappings.groovy). In the index method of that Controller, check if the user is logged in (via SpringSecurity's API). If the user is logged in, render your logged in view, else render your not logged in view. This way, the URL stays the same.

Here is an extract from [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#springSecurityService) of the plugin :

```
class SomeController {
    def springSecurityService

    def index() {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() && SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted("USER_ROLE")) { // Example here checks if we have the "USER_ROLE"
            render view: "A"
        }
        else {
            render view: "B"
        }
    }
}
```

Beware of the *Anonymous* role. It will successfully pass the *isLoggedIn* as specified in the documentation.

Comment: Could you provide code snippet for checking that in the controller? (The exact SpringSecurity API that identify the ROLE and if the User logged in) in the index() function?